# When I append an element it does it twice rather than once

Tags: javascript, comments, createelement

I am trying to make multiple comment boxes for a website. The first click to create the text area and submit button works fine. However when I click another it appends the text area and submit button twice - creating two text areas and submit buttons and then three and so on..

If you go to https://alexpd93.github.io/FAC-Website/ and click on various comment buttons it should make more sense.

I would like it so that each time I click on the comment button, it only creates one text area for each section.

How can I fix this?

```js
function addComment(element) {
  const boxContainer = element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  const commentContainer = element.parentNode;
  commentContainer.classList.add("comment-container-after-click");

  const commentBox = document.createElement("textarea");
  commentBox.classList.add("comment-box-after-click");
  commentBox.placeholder = "What are your thoughts?";
  commentBox.innerHTML = "";

  const submitComment = document.createElement("button");
  submitComment.classList.add("submit-comment-after-click");
  submitComment.innerHTML = "Comment";

  commentContainer.append(commentBox, submitComment);

  submitComment.onclick = function submitComment() {
    let comment = commentBox.value;
    const newComments = document.createElement("p");
    boxContainer.appendChild(newComments);
    newComments.innerHTML = `${comment}`;
    commentBox.value = "";
  };
}

function comment(event) {
  const commentButton = event.target;
  commentButton.style.display = "none";
  const commentIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("comment-icon");

  const iconArray = Array.from(commentIcon);
  iconArray.forEach((icon) => {
    if (icon.nextElementSibling.style.display === "none") {
      icon.style.display = "none";
      addComment(commentButton);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="comments-container" id="comments">
    <img id="commentIcon" class="comment-icon" src="Images/Comment.png" alt="comment icon">
<button class="comment-button" id="commentButton" onclick="comment(event)" > Comment </button>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the behavior you describe is the logic in your scripts. So to answer "how to fix this" you will need to also describe the desired behavior you prefer in plain language.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the website I believe I understood the problem. You are calling `addComment()` for all elements with class `comment-icon`. And due to your (tbh) little bit weird handling of `addComment()` this adds a comment to every single one of this elements.

I've corrected the error below and marked my changes with comments.

```js
function addComment(element) {
  const boxContainer = element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  const commentContainer = element.parentNode;
  commentContainer.classList.add("comment-container-after-click");

  const commentBox = document.createElement("textarea");
  commentBox.classList.add("comment-box-after-click");
  commentBox.placeholder = "What are your thoughts?";
  commentBox.innerHTML = "";

  const submitComment = document.createElement("button");
  submitComment.classList.add("submit-comment-after-click");
  submitComment.innerHTML = "Comment";

  commentContainer.append(commentBox, submitComment);

  submitComment.onclick = function submitComment() {
    let comment = commentBox.value;
    const newComments = document.createElement("p");
    // why append to the box container? Then all comments from different textareas will be merged
    // boxContainer.appendChild(newComments);
    commentContainer.appendChild(newComments);
    newComments.innerHTML = `${comment}`;
    commentBox.value = "";
  };
}

function comment(event) {
  const commentButton = event.target;
  commentButton.style.display = "none";
  const commentIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("comment-icon");

  // add the comment once not to every comment box available
  addComment(commentButton);

  const iconArray = Array.from(commentIcon);
  iconArray.forEach((icon) => {
    if (icon.nextElementSibling.style.display === "none") {
      icon.style.display = "none";
      // this causes that the comment is added multiple times
      // addComment(commentButton);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div div="all-comments">
  <div class="comments-container" id="comments">
    <img id="commentIcon" class="comment-icon" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="comment icon">
    <button class="comment-button" id="commentButton" onclick="comment(event)"> Comment </button>
  </div>
  <div class="comments-container" id="comments">
    <img id="commentIcon" class="comment-icon" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="comment icon">
    <button class="comment-button" id="commentButton" onclick="comment(event)"> Comment </button>
  </div>
  <div class="comments-container" id="comments">
    <img id="commentIcon" class="comment-icon" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="comment icon">
    <button class="comment-button" id="commentButton" onclick="comment(event)"> Comment </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And good work for understanding my weird way of writing code :)